# xgettext gives me a strange output for a simple line:

Tags: php, linux, shell, xgettext

I'm using xgettext to greate a .po file. But it gives me a strange output for a simple line:

```
<?php echo _("You must click the link to verify your e-mail and activate your account."); ?>
```

Results in:

```
msgid ""
"You must click the link to verify your e-mail and activate your account."
msgstr ""
```

When i remove the - or the dot, everything works fine.

Is there a solution/known bug? I'm really confused :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change the line to this:

```
<?php echo _("You must click the link to verify your e\-mail and activate your account\."); ?>
```

and that should escape the characters.

Comment: Yeah of course, but i was looking for an other solution. Just like a flag for the xgettext command to ignore those chars.